# no rewrite on specific folder - htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current `.htaccess`-File looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?g=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?g=$1&pt=$2 [L,QSA]
```

There is the physical folder install.

If I try to open `http://example.com/install` instead of opening the `install/index.php` it tries to open `index.php?g=install`.
No wonder here, because, thats what I wanted.
But how can I still open the `install`-Folder.
Everything go to index, but install go to install ...

I tried something like this: 
`RewriteRule ^install/index\.php$ /install/index.php [R=301,L,NC]`

Still not working.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bypass rule for `/install/` URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

# skip /install/ from rules below
RewriteRule ^install/?$ - [L,NC]

# skip all directories and files from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# handle single level virtual folder 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?g=$1 [L,QSA]

# handle 2 level virtual folders 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?g=$1&pt=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you AGAIN for your fast and right answer.

Can you just explain, was you did there?

Comment: I've just added comment before each rule in answer to explain in clearly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wait! install/index.php is working, but not the other rules anymore ... like: 
`http://127.0.0.1/folder/1/5` ... also tried: `http://127.0.0.1/folder/1/5/`

Comment: Sorry, I don't now, what I did ... Working now, after I copied your answer again! - so Thanks, it's working!

Just another question: I am right: If there is a directory, it will open Directory, if it isn't, it will redirect to index.php?

Comment: Thats what `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` is doing?
What is the [OR] in the First `RewriteCond`for?

Comment: @Haudegen If the requested path exists either as a file __or__ a directory, leave the url as it is.

Comment: That rule means **if it is a file OR if it is a directory then do nothing**.

Comment: Thank you very much! You just have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer as the right one. :-)